# linq to entities connection string

Tags: string, entity-framework, connection

Just finished my project. Tested and fully functioned on my local machine, but when I deploy to my host I am getting the following error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

For your info my Connection String in Web.Config looks like:

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TVTMainDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.TVTModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.TVTModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.TVTModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TVTMainDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="FAQString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TVTMainDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Local Machine(PC1) is different in your host machine(PC2) that's why this error occurs.

./ means your ServerName and SQLEXPRESS is your named instance.

What you should do is to Complete the connection string and register your host on your local pc sqlexpres login.(windows authentication)

```
Data Source=yourServerAddress/SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=YourDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Or much better if you create username password on your database (sql server authentication).

```
Data Source=myServerAddress/SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=yourDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

see: [connectionstring.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Regards

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. After I changed the server address, Now I am getting this error: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.